# For each 1000 rows, insert new incrementing date python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
       a     b     c   
0      1     2     3
1      4     5     6
...
1000   7     8     9
```

I'm trying to create a column `d` with an incrementing date for each 1000 rows, like this:

```
       a     b     c    d
0      1     2     3    4/1/21
1      4     5     6    4/1/21
2      4     5     6    4/1/21
...
1000   7     8     9    4/2/21
1001   7     8     9    4/2/21
...
2000   7     8     9    4/3/21
2001   7     8     9    4/3/21
```

I think I should pass in a list of the dates, but I really don't know the best way to do this. I'm doing it manually in excel.

Comment: The start date is 4/1/21?

Comment: @HenryEcker Yep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try something like:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Random Data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(2002, 3)),
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

start = pd.to_datetime("4/1/2021")
df['d'] = start + (df.index // 1000 * pd.Timedelta(days=1))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      a  b  c          d
0     7  9  6 2021-04-01
1     3  5  6 2021-04-01
2     7  5  8 2021-04-01
3     8  2  3 2021-04-01
4     6  6  8 2021-04-01
...  .. .. ..        ...
1997  4  3  7 2021-04-02
1998  1  5  2 2021-04-02
1999  1  7  7 2021-04-02
2000  4  8  8 2021-04-03
2001  9  9  6 2021-04-03

[2002 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: awesome, bro that first one works. I'll keep the updated version just in case.